# Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader

Tags: oauth2

I am using OAuth2 for connecting my app with user's salesforce account. I am making authorization request with success and getting following things in response

1. access_token
2. instance_url
3. id
4. issued_at
5. signature
6. scope
7. token_type: Bearer

When I am trying to fetch salesforce data with following code

```
Dim binding As sforce.SforceService
binding = New sforce.SforceService()
binding.SessionHeaderValue = New sforce.SessionHeader()
binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = <<access_token>> ' This is obtained by above step
binding.Url = <<id>> ' This is obtained by above step
dgr = binding.describeSObject("case")
```

I am getting exception

> INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal
>   Session. Session not found, missing session hash:
>   dGNP7MWaYz4kTAATqdvCAQk8H5NxD/xw/L+PpuPMpFA= This error usually occurs
>   after a session expires or a user logs out.

How can I fix it? I am sure I am passing something wrong but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

binding.Url should be the instance_url and not the Id.

SRC: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET

We only need 2 params to make successive calls, sessionId and serverURL. As you are using Oauth2 to get access token it also gives you server_url in the form of instance_url.